# I am trying to use OR condition in Teredata

Tags: sql, teradata

Here is my condition

Code :

```
Select * 
from table_name 
where col1 is not null
or (col1 is null and col2 = 1) 
and Col3 in (1,2,3,4);
```

This is not working for me, it will work only when I use Condition in Bracket 
Code :

```
Select * 
from table_name 
where (
  col1 is not null or 
  (col1 is null and col2 = 1)   
)
and Col3 in (1,2,3,4);
```

Can anyone help to understand how OR condition works?

Comment: Define _"This is not working for me"_. You get an error message? What do you mean by that? Please share sample data and expected results as _formatted text not images_. Also which DBMS you're using `SQL` is just a language.

Comment: What happens when you change it to `where col1 is not null or (col1 is null and col2 = 1 and Col3 in (1,2,3,4));`?

Comment: @Sami The title says Teradata, so I will assume that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yup, I just don't trust what new users writes and ask them again, because they usually don't know what's DBMS or SQL Server isn't MySQL... . Thus I ask again for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that while your query does run, it does not generate the result set you are expecting.  Try adding parentheses which make more sense:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE
    (col1 IS NOT NULL OR col2 = 1) AND
    col3 IN (1,2,3,4);
```

The null check on `col1` and the backup check on `col2` would seem to belong together, so they should both happen inside parentheses.  Not that you don't need to check for `col1 IS NULL`, because if the non null check fails, it automatically means that `col1` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you mix `AND` and `OR` in your `WHERE` clause without parentheses you are setting yourself up for trouble.  Using an `OR` like this effectively negates the `AND` will give you unexpected results.

The `OR` check just means to return rows where either the "left" condition or the "right" condition evaluates to `TRUE`.  In your case without the parentheses, your query will always return rows if the `OR` condition evaluates to `TRUE` and will ignore the `AND col3 IN (...)` check.

I'm guessing you want something more like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_name
WHERE (
  col1 IS NOT NULL OR
  (col1 IS NULL AND col2 = 1)
)
AND col3 IN (1,2,3,4);
```

This will tighten up the logic around `col1` while preserving the filter on `col3`.

Comment: And the reason "getting trouble" is the order of precedence for boolean logic `NOT - AND - OR`  :-)